# Qlik sense: Order Line Graph by Date Dimension

Tags: qliksense

I have a master calendar table and two different data sources to get inventory details (owned, repair, rented). I am using interval match on the rented data using the out and in date. However, when creating the line graph, the dates are completely all over the place.

Here is some parts of the data :

```
RentIntervals:
IntervalMatch(IDate,InventoryKey)
LOAD outdatetime, indatetime,InventoryKey
Resident LoadRented;

/*Concatenate(RentIntervals)
Load * resident LoadDailyOwnedRepairInventory;*/

INNER Join (RentIntervals)
Load * Resident LoadRented;
Concatenate Load * Resident LoadDailyOwnedRepairInventory;
```

Is there a way I can order this data?

When I run the sheet without any filters the data are all jumbled up until I select the year and month, then it's fine. 
I have a sort on the data field but it doesn't seem to be making any difference.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you share a QVW or some screenshots? Does the date sort correctly (by default) if you throw it in a listbox by itself? Big-picture, your chart is going to expect a numberic x-axis, so a lot of time formatting to make dates readable screws that up.

Answer (score 0):

To change sorting in QlikSense, edit the sheet, click the chart to edit, on the right hand side there will be a sorting tab (you may need to minimize the data tab to see this). Sense tries to sort as it sees best, but you can rearrange your dimensions and change how the sorting is applied.

In your case, I would move the date to the top, turn off custom sorting and set it to sort numerically.

[image: QlikSense Sorting tab from Qlik example dashboard]